# In ∆PQR. S and T are the mid point of PQ and QR respectively. If the area of the Triangle PQR is 48 cm^2 what is the area of the triangle SQT in cm²?

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle PQR$ $S$ and $T$ are the mid point of $PQ$ and $QR$ respectively. If the area of the Triangle $\triangle PQR$ is $48 cm^2$, what is the area of the triangle $\triangle SQT$ (in $cm^2$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @snehasingh. What is your attempt? What did you try??

Comment: Can you show us your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to Maths SE.

$S, T$ is the midpoint of $PQ,QR.$ $\implies$
$ST $ parallel to $PR\implies \Delta QST $ is similar to$\Delta QPR$.

Can you take the problem ahead now?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint $\# 1$:** Think about the formula for the area of a triangle $\frac{1}{2}bh$. If you draw the problem, notice that you can show that $\triangle SQT$ and $\triangle PQR$ are similar by some scale factor. How does that scale factor change when applied to the area inside of side length of a shape?

**Hint $\#2$:** What happens to a triangle's area when it's base relative to some altitude is halved?